# How to replace reference in maya?

Tags: python, python-2.7, maya

I am trying to write a script a script of replacing multiple references in maya .

Suppose there are 5 references and i want to replace 4 references from other path with diffrent extension for e.g asset.ma to asset.gpu. But not getting how to proceed..able to do with one references but not with multiple.

Please help

Answer (score 0):

you can find all ref with this :

```
refNodes = cmds.ls(type="reference")
```

Here is a simple loop to process them. I let you zip or associate current reference and the one you want to replace

```
for i in refNodes:
    if i == 'myrefRN':
        ref= cmds.referenceQuery (i, f=True)
        # pathNewRef = "X:\\folder\\myref.ma" 
        # or mayabe in your case
        # pathNewRef.replace('.ma', '.gpu')
        cmds.file(pathNewRef, loadReference = i)
```

You are new but you must be aware that providing a piece of code is more cool and will give a concrete things to correct. Cheers !

Answer (score 0):

DrWeeny's response does not work for Maya 2018, the MEL equivalent works but the python commands only reloads the original referenced file, Autodesk knows of this and advises updating to Maya 2019. Although, in a company setting, upgrading to 2019 might not be feasible.